# How to create a summary table to use in model pandas python

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataset

```
# Import pandas library 
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# initialize list of lists 
data = [['tom', 10,1], ['tom', 15,5], ['tom', 14,1], ['tom', 15,4], ['tom', 18,1], ['tom', 15,6], ['tom', 17,3]
       , ['tom', 14,7], ['tom',16 ,6], ['tom', 22,2],['matt', 10,1], ['matt', 15,5], ['matt', 14,1], ['matt', 15,4], ['matt', 18,1], ['matt', 15,6], ['matt', 17,3]
       , ['matt', 14,7], ['matt',16 ,6], ['matt', 22,2]] 

# Create the pandas DataFrame 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Attempts','Score']) 
print(df)
   Name  Attempts  Score
0    tom        10      1
1    tom        15      5
2    tom        14      1
3    tom        15      4
4    tom        18      1
5    tom        15      6
6    tom        17      3
7    tom        14      7
8    tom        16      6
9    tom        22      2
10  matt        10      1
11  matt        15      5
12  matt        14      1
13  matt        15      4
14  matt        18      1
15  matt        15      6
16  matt        17      3
17  matt        14      7
18  matt        16      6
19  matt        22      2
```

The i added some custom metrics to get the previous 3 and 5 moving averages for the column `Attempts`:

```
#AVE TIME OF LAST 3/5 Attempts
df['Ave3Attempts']=df.groupby('Name').Attempts.apply(lambda x : x.shift().rolling(3,min_periods=1).mean().fillna(x))
df['Ave5Attempts']=df.groupby('Name').Attempts.apply(lambda x : x.shift().rolling(5,min_periods=1).mean().fillna(x))
print(df.round(2))

    Name  Attempts  Score  Ave3Attempts  Ave5Attempts
0    tom        10      1         10.00          10.0
1    tom        15      5         10.00          10.0
2    tom        14      1         12.50          12.5
3    tom        15      4         13.00          13.0
4    tom        18      1         14.67          13.5
5    tom        15      6         15.67          14.4
6    tom        17      3         16.00          15.4
7    tom        14      7         16.67          15.8
8    tom        16      6         15.33          15.8
9    tom        22      2         15.67          16.0
10  matt        10      1         10.00          10.0
11  matt        15      5         10.00          10.0
12  matt        14      1         12.50          12.5
13  matt        15      4         13.00          13.0
14  matt        18      1         14.67          13.5
15  matt        15      6         15.67          14.4
16  matt        17      3         16.00          15.4
17  matt        14      7         16.67          15.8
18  matt        16      6         15.33          15.8
19  matt        22      2         15.67          16.0
```

I have then used this set to create a model to predict `Score` through `sklearn` train/test using those `Ave3Attempts`  and `Ave5Attempts` columns.

Now that I have my model I am trying to create a summary table of the most recent data for each person to then look up to predict the `score`

Essentially trying to produce a new dataframe to then use as part of a new prediction:

```
      Name    Ave3Attempts  Ave5Attempts
0    tom         17.33          16.8
1    matt        17.33          16.8
```

Any help on how to do this would be great! thanks!

Comment: In your output solution, where are the values `17.33` and `16.8` coming from ?

Comment: Hi @pyOliv. The `17.33` is coming from averaging the last 3 `attempts` for each person and the `16.8` from the last 5 `attempts`. It just happens that both tom and matt have the same data

Comment: OK, this is misunderstanding with input data that are all below these values. So for `tom`, `Ave3Attempts` is the average for attemps #22 #18 and #17 ? The 3 biggest values.

Comment: thanks @pyOliv. So I'm trying to offset the averages so that the in last row for `tom` the `Ave3Attempts` is calculated from `2nd last + 3rd last + 4th last` entry which it is doing correctly. So when trying to creat the summary table I am trying to calculate `tom` average which would be from row `9, 8, 7` which would be `22+16+14` equalling `17.33`. but how to get that summary table im not quite sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code:

```py
df2 = pd.DataFrame([], index=df['Name'].unique())
# looping through names
for name in df['Name'].unique():
    df2.loc[name, "Ave3Attempts"] = df[ df['Name']==name ]['Attempts'].tail(3).mean()
    df2.loc[name, "Ave5Attempts"] = df[ df['Name']==name ]['Attempts'].tail(5).mean()
print(df2)
```

Comment: hi @pyOliv, I am getting a `ValueError: Incompatible indexer with Series` when doing the same thing as the suggested answer. When i print the index everything looks fine so im not sure what is wrong

Comment: i am trying to add a new culumn called rank, which ranks the last `Attempts` item in the `df` and add it. I have tried `df2.loc[name, "rank"] = df[ df['Name']==name ]['Attempts'].tail(1).rank(ascending=False)`

Comment: For your first question, what version of pandas are you using ? For the second one, the basic of this loop is `df2.loc[name, "rank"] = scalar`. Then you have to play with values to be sure that you pass a scalar. Otherwise, it will raise an exception.