# How to perform Groupby, Rank and Sum calculations across different dataframes in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

As an extension to this question [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62112717/how-to-create-a-summary-table-to-use-in-model-pandas-python/62113565#62113565) I now have an extra categorical column that I'm trying to do some further calculations on. Data:

```
#summary table question

# Import pandas library 
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# initialize list of lists 
data = [['tom', 10,1,'a'], ['tom', 15,5,'a'], ['tom', 14,1,'a'], ['tom', 15,4,'b'], ['tom', 18,1,'b'], ['tom', 15,6,'a'], ['tom', 17,3,'a']
       , ['tom', 14,7,'b'], ['tom',16 ,6,'a'], ['tom', 22,2,'a'],['matt', 10,1,'a'], ['matt', 15,5,'b'], ['matt', 14,1,'b'], ['matt', 15,4,'a'], ['matt', 18,1,'a'], ['matt', 15,6,'a'], ['matt', 17,3,'a']
       , ['matt', 14,7,'a'], ['matt',16 ,6,'b'], ['matt', 10,2,'b']]

# Create the pandas DataFrame 
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Name', 'Attempts','Score','Category']) 
print(df)
      Name  Attempts  Score Category
0    tom        10      1        a
1    tom        15      5        a
2    tom        14      1        a
3    tom        15      4        b
4    tom        18      1        b
5    tom        15      6        a
6    tom        17      3        a
7    tom        14      7        b
8    tom        16      6        a
9    tom        22      2        a
10  matt        10      1        a
11  matt        15      5        b
12  matt        14      1        b
13  matt        15      4        a
14  matt        18      1        a
15  matt        15      6        a
16  matt        17      3        a
17  matt        14      7        a
18  matt        16      6        b
19  matt        10      2        b
```

Calculations from previous question:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame([], index=df['Name'].unique())
# looping through names
for name in df['Name'].unique():
    df2.loc[name, "Ave3Attempts"] = df[ df['Name']==name ]['Attempts'].tail(3).mean()
    df2.loc[name, "Ave5Attempts"] = df[ df['Name']==name ]['Attempts'].tail(5).mean()

print(df2)

      Name    Ave3Attempts  Ave5Attempts
0    tom         17.33          16.8
1    matt        13.33          14.4
```

Now hoping to get also:

```
      Name    Ave3Attempts  Ave5Attempts     LastrankByGroup   sumA    sumB
0    tom         17.33          16.8               1            109    47
1    matt        13.33          14.4               4            89    55
```

i have tried:

```
df2.loc[name, "LastrankByGroup"] =df[df['Name']==name['Attempts'].tail(1).groupby(['Name','Category']).rank(ascending=False)
df2.loc[name, "sumA"] = df[ df['Name']==name ]['Attempts'].sum(df['Category']=='a')
df2.loc[name, "sumB"] = df[ df['Name']==name ]['Attempts'].sum(df['Category']=='b')
```

but no such luck. Can anyone suggest the best way to write these out? I think I am getting the orders wrong on my `groupby()` and `tail()` as well as the `sum()` function. Thanks!

Comment: For the sum just do this: `df2.loc[name, "sumA"] = df[ (df['Name']==name) & (df["Category"] == "a" )]['Attempts'].sum()`, and change `sumA` and `=="b"` for `b`

Comment: I don't get how the column `LastrankByGroup` is computed, could you explain it a bit better please?

Comment: thanks @DavideBrex. The `LastrankByGroup` column is taking the last value for each person and ranking it against the `Category` of each person. Hope that makes sense!

Comment: With last value you mean the `Attempts` value in row 9 for tom and row 19 for matt? So a  `LastrankByGroup` value of 4 for matt comes from the 4th position of value 10 in the ranking of `Attempts` with `Category` == b?